# SoapUI mock service: use host from request in the response

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I'm building a REST mock service with SoapUI, and the issue is that the response must refer to another endpoint on the same service. So I have a mock action with a response like:

```
{
    ...,
    "url": "http://localhost:8082/path/to/endpoint"
}
```

But the **scheme, host, and port** parameters must be the same as in the incoming request (so that the mock can be used e.g. in a Docker container without any modification).

I tried to use `"url": "${=modelItem.localEndpoint}/path/to/endpoint"`, but it isn't quite working as the host-part is always the same as in the project.

I know I can write a script for extracting the corresponding values from the HTTP request, but I'd like to avoid that and just use property substitution.

Answer (score 0):

When I am testing REST in SoapUI I used to define project property `#Project#apiEndpoint` then use it in the definition of Service Endpoint(It allows easy switch between eg. Production and Staging environment).
[image]

In your case, you can easily reuse this property in the Mock service definition.

Comment: In my case the point is it has to be the same as in the incoming request. Because it can run locally, on the host, or in a Docker container (whose name you don't know in advance).

Comment: How about fixing docker container name by passing it by `--name` docker parameter and pass the same value via `-e` ie. `docker run --name $GENERATED -e ENDPOINT=$GENERATED some_container_img`. Then pass the env variable to soapui runner you used, and set it as project variable.